# Intersection of plane and parametric line

Tags: linear-algebra

The plane is $x-y-z=0$ and the parametric line is $x=2,y=t,z=t$ where $t$ is the parameter and $t \in \mathbb{R} $

Well I get that $2-x-z=0 \iff 2-t-t=0 \iff 2=2t \iff 1=t \iff y=z=1$

So the intersection point is $x=2,y=1,z=1$

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right, because the point $(2, t, t)$ lying on the line will also lie on the plane: $x-y-z=0$ & so it will satisfy the equation of plane. hence your answer is correct